# How to make a distinction between <a> with & without href in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm crawling a website and the target is the ads ID's, I was crawling a tags, then ['href'], but some of a tags don't have href, and return an error.

How can I make a distinction between these two?
The code:

```
def id_finder(url):
    id_list = []
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    ads_ids = soup.find_all('a')
    for ID in ads_ids:
        link = ID['href']
        if link.find('/car-search/'):
            pass
        else:
            print(link)

           
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./chromedriver")
    driver.get("https://iranpelak.com/car-search")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-role='end']"))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    first_page_url = driver.current_url
    for page in range(1, 10000):
        if page == 1:
            id_finder(first_page_url)
        else:
            pass
```

The error I get:

```
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

I think it's because some a tags don't have href, but your opinions would be appreciated!

Comment: you can use `.get()` method or handle the `KeyError`

Comment: There's probably an XPATH expression that you could use to ensure that the <a> elements returned always contain an href attribute. However, it's just as easy to utilise the *in* keyword to check if the *ID* actually has an href attribute before trying to acquire it. Another way is to use a *try/except* which I personally find neater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a try/except block to handle those tags which do not contain a `href` element, catching the `KeyError` that is thrown:

```
for ID in ads_ids:
    try:
        link = ID['href']
    except KeyError:
        # Handle cases here
    if link.find('/car-search/'):
        pass
    else:
        print(link)
```

If you don't need to handle anything here, you can simply use `continue` to skip to the next iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer to your question is that [you can pass custom function (filter)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to `soup.find_all()` method:

```
spam = """
<a href="some url">a tag with href</a>
<a>a tag without href</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'html.parser')

# find all a tags 
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in a_tags:
    print(tag.text)

# find only a tags with href
a_tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.get('href'))
for tag in a_tags:
    print(tag.text)
    print(tag['href']) # or print(tag.get('href'))
```

output

```
a tag with href
a tag without href
a tag with href
some url
```

However, as mentioned in the comments it is possible to use `tag.get()` method or handle the `KeyError` exception

```
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in a_tags:
    link = tag.get('href')
    if link:
        print(link)


a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in a_tags:
    try:
        link = tag['href']
        print(link)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

output

```
some url
some url
```

Answer (score 1):

You can condense this:

```
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')

for ID in ads_ids:
    link = ID['href']
    if link.find('/car-search/'):
        pass
    else:
        print(link)
```

into this:

```
print([i['href'] for i in soup.select('a[href]:not([href*="/car-search/"])')])
```

**`a[href]`** -> `a` tags only with `href` attribute;

**`:not([href*="/car-search/"])`** -> `hrefs` not containing the string `/car-search/`

Combining them specifies `a` tags only with `href` attributes not containing the specified string.

This css selector list is applied via `select()` method, returning a list which can have the `href` attributes extracted, from each member, inside a list comprehension. The extracted list of hrefs are wrapped in a `print()` call.